# Seeking spark conf to handle error in spark3 and not in spark2: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) . missing from

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am migrating some of my jobs from spark 2.8 to spark 3.3. One of my report is experiencing the following error when run using spark3-submit.

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) MASKED_COLUMN_NAME missing from ...
Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: MASKED_COLUMN_NAME. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.;

I was hoping if anyone is aware of any spark sql configurations (--conf etc) i can add to my spark3-submit file to resolve this error. I have exhausted and tried the relevant confs in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html but to no avail. Thank you for reading!

Comment: It's likely no configuration item will change this and that it's the code that's wrong (just happened to work on 2.x), can you post a minimised code sample that reproduces this?